# Find the solution of congruence equation $56x=23(mod93)$ between $0≤x<93$ using Euclidean algorithm.

Tags: congruences, euclidean-algorithm

I have no idea how to do it. Hope somebody can explain how to solve it.

Comment: Explain what? Write properly where you got stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $56$ and $93$ are relatively prime, so $56$ has a multiplicative inverse in $\Bbb Z_{93}$. Hence, there exists $u\in\Bbb Z_{93}$ such that $56u\equiv 1\mod 93$, and thus $x\equiv 23u\mod 93$. You can find $u$ through the equation $56u+93v=1$, which is from Bezout's lemma due to the fact that $\gcd(56,93)=1$.

Notice that $56\cdot 5=280$ and $93\cdot 3=279$, so $56\cdot 5+93\cdot -3=1$. Hence, $u=5$ is the multiplicative inverse of $56$ in $\Bbb Z_{93}$. Thus, $$x\equiv 23\cdot 5\mod 93\implies x\equiv 115\mod 93\implies x\equiv 22\mod 93$$

Answer (score 0):

$$  \gcd( 93, 56 ) = ???    $$

$$ \frac{ 93 }{ 56 } = 1 +  \frac{ 37 }{ 56 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 56 }{ 37 } = 1 +  \frac{ 19 }{ 37 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 37 }{ 19 } = 1 +  \frac{ 18 }{ 19 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 19 }{ 18 } = 1 +  \frac{ 1 }{ 18 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 18 }{ 1 } = 18 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 } $$ 
 Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 18 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 1 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 2 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }   & &   \frac{ 5 }{ 3 }   & &   \frac{ 93 }{ 56 }  
 \end{array}
 $$ 
 $$  $$ 
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{ccc}
  \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 1 }{ 1 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 2 }{ 1 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 5 }{ 3 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  18  \\  
  \frac{ 93 }{ 56 }   &     \mbox{digit}  &  0  \\  
 \end{array}
 $$

$$ 93 \cdot 3 - 56 \cdot 5 = -1 $$

In particular,
$$ 56 \cdot 5 \equiv 1 \pmod {93} $$